# Failed to install libapache2-mod-php

Tags: php, linux

I tried to install libapache2-mod-php on debian 11. but

```
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.4 (7.4.25-1+deb11u1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.4 (--configure):
  installed libapache2-mod-php7.4 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php:
  libapache2-mod-php depends on libapache2-mod-php7.4; however:
   Package libapache2-mod-php7.4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
  libapache2-mod-php7.4
  libapache2-mod-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

returns this error and won't install.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I ve encounted this error recently. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I think worked for me. Then purge, update and force install. Have a look in this [article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1).